# call a number using skype in a webpage

Tags: skype

I am trying to add a link or button to the webpage so that the user can call a number directly if the skype is installed. it seems the link is like

skyp:....?call....

but cannot find any sample or documents. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Skype has a description of their URIs on their developer site:

http://dev.skype.com/skype-uri

How well these work is entirely up to your browser and OS.

Comment: I think the URL has changed since MS took over.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745881%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 10):

This is the format for the link:

```
<a href="skype:echo123?call">Click</a> (make a call to echo123)
```

It will work provided the visitor have Skype installed.

You can find all the options and an alternative javascript to redirect the user to download skype is he/she does not have Skype installed.

http://dev.skype.com/skype-uri

Comment: i think the URL has changed since MS took over.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745881%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: I just tried this method and it worked for me. It wasn't working for me when I was using http:// in front of skype

Comment: Very useful answer, and @johnsnails , TX for the link correction.. it will help a rookie coder (like ME) learn about skype calls from webpage. TY

Answer (score 7):

```
<a href="skype:+CountryCodePhoneNumber?call">Click</a>
```

(make a call to any PHONE NUMBER)

Please note that the Country Code is required. Without it call option will not show. If your database has numbers without country code, you can add the country code as +1 in your script. Skype will then give you the option to change country code before calling so you can change to required country if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Skype is a client program. You may have two options: Write an url handler that calls Skype and use that url. Somewhat like my-skype://.

There's a plugin (at least for IE) too. You would need to make sure, your numbers are recognizable (in the correct format).

Answer (score 1):

This has change, now you have to create a javascript function to create a button in order to make a call from the browser.

You can have a function like this and send the number you want to call.

You will need the js url from skype for this to work. Please visit skype sdk documentation for this url, this can change.

```
 function CreateSkypeButton(id, number) {

            Skype.ui({
                name: "call",
                element: "call_",
                participants: ["+1" + number],
                imageSize: 24,
                imageColor: "blue"
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If Skype  and its web toolbar is installed it automatically detects phone numbers in web pages and adds a menu to near the phone number. So I dont think you should do anything do enable it in your web page.